# FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

so here I want to store the image URL from the firebase storage in firestore. I am getting an error of undefined as my setImgUrl is undefined. please help me to solve this.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../mainTab.css";
import "./addScreen.css";

import firebase, { storage } from "../firebase";


const AddScreen = () => {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const [cat, setCat] = useState();
  const [course, setCourse] = useState();
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [price, setPrice] = useState();
  const [descrip, setDescrip] = useState();
  const [image, setImage] = useState();
  const [imgURL, setImgURL] = useState();

  const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const ref = storage.ref(`/images/${image.name}`);
    const uploadTask = ref.put(image);
    uploadTask.on("state_changed", console.log, console.error, () => {
      ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
        setImage(null);
        setImgURL(url);
        console.log(imgURL);
      });
    });

    const data = {
      name: name,
      price: price,
      cat: cat,
      course: course,
      decription: descrip,
      image: imgURL,
    };

    db.collection("menu")
      .doc(course.toString())
      .collection(name.toString())
      .add(data)
      .then(() => alert("menu item is posted"))
      .catch((error) => alert("error: " + error));

    setName("");
    setPrice("");
    setCat("");
    setCourse("");
    setImage("");
    setDescrip("");
  };
```

I need the img URL in the setImg hook.
so is there any way after completing the upload I should call the database writing function(I tries with a flag(false) hook which didn't help?
by the image get uploaded perfectly fine into the firebase storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any code that needs the download URL from Firebase, needs to be inside the `then` callback, be called from there, or synchronized to run once `imgURL` is set in some other way.

The simplest way to fix your code, is to move the code that writes to Firestore into the `then` block like this:

```
const ref = storage.ref(`/images/${image.name}`);
const uploadTask = ref.put(image);
uploadTask.on("state_changed", console.log, console.error, () => {
  ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
    setImage(null);
    setImgURL(url);
    console.log(imgURL);

    const data = {
      name: name,
      price: price,
      cat: cat,
      course: course,
      decription: descrip,
      image: url, //  Use url here, as imgURL won't be set yet
    };

    db.collection("menu")
      .doc(course.toString())
      .collection(name.toString())
      .add(data)
      .then(() => alert("menu item is posted"))
      .catch((error) => alert("error: " + error));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting this part inside a function and then call that function inside 'then'
say for example

```
    const putUrl = ()=>{
    db.collection("menu")
      .doc(course.toString())
      .collection(name.toString())
      .add(data)
      .then(() => alert("menu item is posted"))
      .catch((error) => alert("error: " + error));

    setName("");
    setPrice("");
    setCat("");
    setCourse("");
    setImage("");
    setDescrip("");
  }
```

and now call putUrl in 'then()' by this way this part of code will execute only after 'imgUrl' is fetched. You got an error because getting 'imgUrl' and adding data are both asynchronous and will get execute before 'imgUrl' is fetched

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field image in document menu/starters/veg Manchurian/3uGgyCcyyQ3KoS60qcUk)

Comment: @AnirudhSaladi the problem may be because state doesn't get updated, try putting data directly without using state

Comment: yeah that worked. I used putUrl(url){//} thanks for the help